# How do you store data retrieved from an API locally in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, local-storage

I'm building an app that retrieves quite a lot of data from an API (around 100MB total) what would be the best way to download all the data from multiple endpoints as a catalog and then have access to it locally?

I use React Native and Redux

Comment: Hi, we can use asyncStorage to store data locally ,
check this link,,
https://medium.com/building-with-react-native/what-is-asyncstorage-in-react-native-and-how-you-to-use-it-with-app-state-manager-1x09-b8c636ce5f6e

Answer (score 0):

You should use a local databse to store that amount of data.
For instance **realm-js** or **sqlite**:
https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/.
https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what CR7 said, you can also use a browser bultin called localStorage (if you do not want yet another dependency) -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage